# Matplotlib plots (fig = plt.figure()) not showing in VS Code

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

### Following way to show a picture works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,5,100)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title("Plot generated using Matplotlib")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("sinx")
plt.show()
```

---

### But following way does not show a picture in VSC:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), '-')
plt.plot(x, np.cos(x), '--');
```

---

By the way, both ways work out pictures in Jupyter notebook.

Where am I wrong? Thank you

Comment: You need `plt.show()` in VSC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib plots not showing in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121948/matplotlib-plots-not-showing-in-vs-code)