# How to plot graph in python (.py) without Jupyter cells in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, plotly, visualization

I don't really like working in Jupyter enviroment and prefer raw Python. Is it posible to plot graphs directly in VSC via .py file? If I put my code to Jupyter cell in Jupyter file (.ipynp) the visualization works fine directly in VSC.

I use plotly or matplotlib, but i am willing to learn other packages if needed.

Is there for example some extencion to VSC that I could use? Or is it posible to plot to jpg/html file that I could open with file explorer?

Edit:
I made a newbie mistake. I didn't use command `plt.show()` to plot the *matplotlib* graph.
But `GNU plotter` suggested by *Charudatta* is also great solution

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121948/matplotlib-plots-not-showing-in-vs-code). I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: have you tried Python Interactive `#%%`, or just launch your python file from the terminal, select a different backend and matplotlib uses a separate graph window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try GNU plotter works great for plotting

Comment: https://github.com/Charudatta999/helpfull/blob/main/gnu_plotter.sh 

you try this I have written a shell program which you could run through wsl

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can, you can't display images in a terminal