# Maplotlib figure not show in vscode jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-widget

The matplotlib figure suddenly doesn't display in vscode's jupyter notebook environment, even though I used:

```py
%matplotlib inline
```

When I plot a figure, e.g.:

```py
data = np.random.randn(1000, 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

only return followings:

```
<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

Here is the versions:

- matploltlib: 3.5.1
- numpy: 1.22.3
- ipython : 8.1.1
- vscode: 1.73.1
- vscode jupyter extension: 2022.9.1303220346

I tried to re-install my vscode and it works, but several days later it happens again.

So if any one knows how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: When I open the same file (even if just open without running) with jupyter notebook instead of the vscode-jupyter-extension, the figures come out.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please check if the discussion from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9697) helps to resolve the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answering! I tried to update `ipympl` to 0.9.1, which works in the context of `%matplotlib widget`, but not helps with `%matplotlib inline` context.

Comment: Can you please try once `plt.gcf()` instead of `plt.show()`? I am just guessing here what might work since I don't have VS Code installed in my machine at this moment.

Comment: Two lines of  `<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>` come out with `plt.gcf()`. I think the key problem is the renderer, because the Figure object returned succesfully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib plots not showing in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121948/matplotlib-plots-not-showing-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to [Matplotlib plots not showing in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954079) works. I just needed to change the display mode of jupyter renderer.

Comment: Could you please add a link of the answer that helped you directly instead of the question link? The linked post contains only 10 answers, so *answer #16* might be confusing for those who are also looking for solutions to a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, those are probably votes and not the # of the answer? The votes change and fluctuate, @Nanxi Chen.